# InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, memorystream

I am trying to read file as a stream in 1 MB chunks. So that load time of the file is better at frontend. But I get below error at backend while trying to do so. Would appreciate your input.

I get below error in the controller:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
   at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
```

itemController:   (Writeline below returns ApplicationName.Shared.ITEMStreamBlock)

```
   var result = await itemRepository.GetFile(fileName, offset, blobLengthRemaining);
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result); // here it returns ApplicationName.Shared.ITEMStreamBlock
   return result;
```

Comment: Mistakenly edited this page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly enough, this happens when you try to return a stream as json (which implicitly happens).

Don't return your object with a memory stream on it. You can maybe return it as a content-stream by setting the content type to `application/octet-stream` and returning a `FileStreamResult`?

Example:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileStreamResult GetTest()
{
  var stream = // your stream
  return new FileStreamResult(stream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"))
  {
    FileDownloadName = "test.txt"
  };
}
```

Otherwise, what you can do is return a byte[] for the section that you want to return instead of just a memory stream. Just don't try to serialize a stream to json by having a property of that type.

Comment: When I use FileStreamResult (stream throws error as cannot convert ITEMStreamBlock to System.IO.Stream). But your answer helped me solve the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please see the modified code above. As suggested, I am returning as byte: By setting -> public byte[] Byte{ get; set; } in ITEMStreamBlock and converting to byte -> retVal.Byte = ms.ToArray();  Hope I am doing it rite. I do not get error now.

Comment: Seems okay. Please use async and await when you return task instead of using GetAwaiter().GetResult();